# drop query taking too long time in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I create function with name `genrate_report()` in **postgresql** that have various query including `create table , joins , update, alter` etc. that work fine and take around **400 ms** to execute on low data and have less connections.

Now data is increasing and now it **300000 ms (around 5 min)** and still that is running.  then I stop that and started to run query one by one. I was wondering that single drop query   `drop table if exists fk_pay_cal;`   takes **781650 ms** and still running.

Is this server error ?
Or too many postgres connection ? (there is 4 connection of remote PgAdmin)

or any other thing ?

Comment: How many rows in `fk_pay_cal`??. A reason could be that other sessions might using that table

Comment: fk_pay_cal now have 56001 row

Comment: whats the output for `select state,
from pg_stat_activity  where query ilike '%fk_pay_cal%'` ?

Comment: That means table is still using by another session !

Comment: If I will Delete All session and than run the query for the time period but this error may come after some time. then what i need to do to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to speed up the process then you need to remove all the constraints from your table as when you are trying to drop the table then the it is first examining the constraints on the table which is taking the time.

Comment: there is no any constraint on that table

Comment: @ShubhamBatra:- Did you check that the table is not getting used in some other session?

Comment: @ShubhamBatra Use `select *  from pg_stat_activity` to check for whether the table(`fk_pay_cal`) is being used by any other sessions or not.

Comment: yes select genrate_report()  is active 11 time. how i can pause this? just changing state or through terminal

Answer (score 0):

`TRUNCATE` will idle until there is no other session using the target table.
Check out [this great stackexchange answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66445/truncate-in-transaction-dead-lock) explaining things in greater detail.